# ASP.Net Identity Identity.IsAuthenticated remains true, even after deleting user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have implemented ASP.Net Identity after following the sample code here:
https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample

In my implementation I check if a user is authenticated - this is called from a FilterAttribute on my MVC Controllers; the idea is i want to confirm they are still auth'ed before serving up the page.

So in my filter, the following code eventually gets called:

```
_authenticationManager.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

`_authenticationManager` is here:

```
private IAuthenticationManager _authenticationManager
{
    get
    {
        return _httpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    }
}
```

The `_httpContext` is passed into the constructor of my identityProvider class.

Now - once I have logged in, `_authenticationManager.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;` returns `true` as expected.

However, during development, i dumped and re-seeded my database, without adding a user. So effectively, I have deleted the IdentityUser - yet `_authenticationManager.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;` STILL returns `true`

any idea why this is? I can only assume it's somehow checking a cookie, rather than actually looking at the DB. is this correct?

Or have i messed up my implementation.....

Comment: Generally speaking, the database is not checked on every request; a cookie (or other mechanism) is storing encrypted details which include the login. Until the backing store is checked again, the login would remain valid.

Comment: hmm... so that to me, makes the `IsAuthenticated` property a waste of space, if not, quite the security hole! i could delete a user to prevent them accessing, and yet this lets them wander right back in.. O_o

Comment: You should lock him out before deleting him like whith to many invalid login attempts

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This does not make `IsAuthenticated` a security hole.  Let's look at the actual authentication process.

1. You setup some stuff in your web.config around where the login page is, how long the login is good for and whether or not to use sliding expiration (should the time be extended if the user is active on your site)
2. User comes to your site, enters their username and password.
3. That information is posted to your server.  You take that information, verify that it is correct (authenticate).  If it is correct, the server then issues an encrypted cookie known as the `FormsAuthenticationTicket` **Note** - this could have a different name in the new Identity stuff, but the same principle.
4. The cookie's contents includes items such as the user name and expiration date of the login.
5. On each request, the server looks at the cookie collection for the authentication cookie.  If found, it decrypts it, reads the values and determines if this is still a valid cookie (expiration time).  Once it has the user information from the cookie, the server can use this information to determine if the user is authorized for the resource requested (look up by username).

5a. If the cookie is not present, or has expired, then the user is redirected back to the login page.

6.When the user logs out, the cookie is deleted from the cookie collection.  Now, if the user tries to go to a resource that is for authorized users only, then the server ends up at 5a above.

So, in your case, you deleted a user manually.  This does not change the fact that this user has previously been authenticated with a still valid cookie.  Therefore, `IsAuthenticated` is returning the expected value.  The user has authenticated before you changed his user status.  `IsAuthenticated` does not mean, is this user still valid in my database.

If you are going to be running a site where you are constantly deleting/deactivating users, then override the `OnRequestAuthorization` method of the `AuthorizeAttribute` to look and see if the user is actually still in the database.  Also, note that if the username is not present (because you deleted it), then any look ups for role / userId will fail.  You can catch that exception / failure and return the property unauthorized response.

Comment: -1

Just wanted to jump in on this given that it's 9 years later. Does Identity/.net-mVC still not have a default way to, on specific events such as user deletion, invalidate their cookies and force a redirect to login?

Comment: @S.B. - I think the JWT based stuff might, but I'm admittedly behind on my knowledge in that area.  In regards to cookie based Identity, as far as I know, what I stated above is still true.  But - again, like my answer and some of the comments posted to the original post state, nothing is preventing you from querying the DB on every request from a user to determine if valid or not.   By default, Identity does not do this as it saves a db query  on each request to your site.  It's up to you as the site admin to determine your level of risk for setting login expiration, user checks, etc