# Why is User.Identity.IsAuthenticated equal true after I restart my dev. server?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I think that internal mechanism of authenticaton should set a cookie with a token and store the same token on a server and next on every request compare the tokens from the cookie and on the server and if they are equal then user is logged in. I don't know where a server stores token, maybe in Session or something else (not persistent), but I'm sure that after the server's restart the server's tokens's store should be cleaned up therefore a user with an old cookie can't be authenticated. But in a practice after I restart my server a user is still authenticated and have access to pages because User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns true. It seems to me wrong. Even if I remove this user from my DB (I use Membership) because I don't want this user have access anymore and restart my server, the user is still authenticated. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 3):

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21271456/2065039)** of answer

Here is how authentication process works.

> - You setup some stuff in your web.config around where the login page    is, how long the login is good for and whether or not to use sliding
>   expiration (should the time be extended if the user is active on your
>   site)
> - User comes to your site, enters their username and password.
> - That information is posted to your server. You take that information,    verify that it is correct (authenticate). If it is
>   correct, the    server then issues an encrypted cookie known as the
>   FormsAuthenticationTicket Note - this could have a different name in
>   the new Identity stuff, but the same principle.
> - The cookie's contents includes items such as the user name and    expiration date of the login.
> - On each request, the server looks at the cookie collection for the    authentication cookie. If found, it decrypts it, reads the values and
>   determines if this is still a valid cookie (expiration time). Once it
>   has the user information from the cookie, the server can use this
>   information to determine if the user is authorized for the resource
>   requested (look up by username).
> - If the cookie is not present, or has expired, or When the user logs out, the cookie is deleted from the cookie collection. Now, if the user tries to go to a resource that is for authorized users only,  then the user is redirected back to the login page.

Hope this helps.